# Plot the solution from DSolve

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I'm trying to solve a differential equation as in the following code:

```
FullSimplify[DSolve[x'[t] == a + b E^(g t) + (c + d E^(-g t)) x[t], x[t], t]]
```

which generates

[image]

Now, I would like to plot it with specific parameter values assigned, for example: `a = 1; b = 2; c = 3; d = 4; g = 0.1; A = 1` where I replaced the integration constant `c_1` with `A`.

Here is my code for plotting `x[t]`:

```
a = 1; b = 2; c = 3; d = 4; g = 0.1; A = 1
x[t_] := E^(-((d E^(-g t))/g) + c t) (A + Integrate[E^((d E^(-g K[1]))/g - c K[1]) (a + b E^(g K[1])), {K[1], 1, t}])
Plot[x[t], {t, 1, 10}]
```

It runs forever. To check whether Mathematica is doing calculations, I tried

```
x[1]
```

and it yielded

```
3.83926*10^-15
```

which is nice. But when I tried

```
x[2]
```

I got

[image]

It seems Mathematica cannot compute the integral unless the integration region is $\int_1^1$. Is this because the integrand is too complicated? Is there any way to let Mathematica compute it? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/95177/piecewise-integration,
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/45450/why-does-evaluating-an-integral-within-a-plot-expression-take-so-long

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It runs forever, since you used `:=` instead of `=` so it was trying to integrate it each time for each different range of `t`.

You need to integrate it once (which will take few seconds), and then use the result instead. Much faster now, since when you change `t`, it will not integrate it again. And changed `g = 0.1` to `g=1/10` as it is best to use exact numbers with `Integrate`

Try

```
ClearAll[t, x]
a = 1; b = 2; c = 3; d = 4; g = 1/10; A = 1;
x[t_] = E^(-((d E^(-g t))/g) + c t) (A + 
     Integrate[
      E^((d E^(-g K[1]))/g - c K[1]) (a + b E^(g K[1])), {K[1], 1, 
       t}]);

Plot[x[t], {t, 1, 3}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Many thanks, Nasser! It was very helpful!